# If $x^2+ax+b=0$ has a rational root, show that the root is an integer.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

So far I have

Assume $a,b,x,y$ are integers; $\frac xy$ is rational; and that $\frac xy$ is in simplest form.

WTS: $\frac xy$ is integer

So $(\frac xy)^2 + a(\frac xy) + b = 0$;

${x^2\over y^2} = -b - a(\frac xy)$;

$x^2 = -by^2- axy$;

$x^2 = y(-by - ax)$;

so $y$ divides $x^2.$

I am having trouble on how to show that $\text{gcd}(x,y)=1.$

Comment: You can assume gcd(x,y)=1, as all rational numbers can be written as x/y with gcd(x,y)=1.

Comment: Ok well that was silly of me. I didn't know that. 

Since y divides x^2 and the gcd(x,y)=1. The there exists an integer r such that x^2=y*r. I can also assume that there exists integers p,q s.t. 1=xp+yq. 

Now starting with 1=xp+yq and multiplying both sides by x, 

x = x^2p + xyq;

x = yrp + yxq = y(rp+xq); 

Since r,x,p,q,(rp+xq) are integers then y divides x; therefore x/y is an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you have already assumed that $\gcd(x,y)=1$ by assuming $x/y$ is in simplest form. All that is left to do is to show that in that case, you have $y=1$. Suppose you can pick a prime number $p$ which divides $y$. Show it divides $x$. This contradiction is what you need to finish the proof.

Answer (score 1):

You have assumed $\cfrac xy$ is in its lowest terms. You need to prove that $y=1$ so that $\cfrac xy$ is an integer.

You have $y|x^2$ so what can the factors of $y$ be if they are not in common with $x$ (by assumption)